# how to access the media gallery in running android emulator

Tags: android, sd-card

I have many files stored in the sdcard of my android emulator. 
On running my app, I want to be able to to access all of them(text/mp3/images) so that the user can select the file.

How can i do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use this snippet

```
String[] id = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
    imageCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
    image_col_index = imageCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
```

Comment: hey! thanks for the reply. but this will only show me the images. i want all the media files at once.